# How to implement (Certbot) ssl using Docker with Nginx image

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, certbot

I'm trying to implement ssl in my application using Docker with nginx image. I have two apps, one for back-end (api) and other for front-end (admin). It's working with http on port 80, but I need to use https. This is my nginx config file...

```
upstream ulib-api {
  server 10.0.2.229:8001;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.ulib.com.br;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://ulib-api;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  client_max_body_size 100M;
}

upstream ulib-admin {
  server 10.0.2.229:8002;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name admin.ulib.com.br;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://ulib-admin;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

I get some tutorials but all is using docker-compose. I need to install it with Dockerfile. Can anyone give me a light?

... I'm using ECS instance on AWS and project is building with CI/CD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one of possible ways:

First issue certificate using `certbot`. You will end up with a couple of `*.pem` files.
There are pretty tutorials on installing and running `certbot` on different systems, I used Ubuntu with command `certbot --nginx certonly`. You need to run this command **on your domain** because `certbot` will check that you are the owner of the domain by a number of challenges.

Second, you create `nginx` containers. You will need proper `nginx.conf` and link certificates to this containers. I use docker volumes but that is not the only way.

My `nginx.conf` looks like following:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /cert/<yourdomain.com>/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /cert/<yourdomain.com>/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /cert/<yourdomain.com>/chain.pem;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ...
    }
}
```

Last, you run `nginx` with proper volumes connected:

```
docker run -d -v $PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -v $PWD/cert:/cert:ro -p 443:443 nginx:1.15-alpine
```

Notice:

- I mapped `$PWD/cert` into container as `/cert`. This is a folder, where `*.pem` files are stored. They live under `./cert/example.com/*.pem`
- Inside `nginx.conf` you refer these certificates with `ssl_...` directives
- You should expose port `443` to be able to connect

Comment: Thanks for answer @grapes, do you now a way to install certbot in DockerFile?

Comment: The same way as you use to install it in host. I use `debian:9-slim` image with `RUN apt-get install --yes nginx certbot python-certbot-nginx` command